# Overview window arrangement with super key not working on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, activities-overview

Whenever I press <kbd>super</kbd> overview of windows should show up, but I am not able to see those. I just upgraded from 18.04 LTS to 19. Please help me out.

[image: Click to see the image of overview]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved after I disabled [windowNavigator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/windownavigator/) extension which I used earlier.

[image: Click to see Image]